# How to prevent Google Places API from producing results from a specific country

Tags: javascript, angular, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I have gone through the entire documentation(https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-service#LocationRestriction) but cannot find a solution

I know how I can limit google autocomplete results to Country only but I am trying to find out how to avoid results from a single country.

I have tried the following code(added the ! operator to avoid results from US):

```
{
componentRestrictions: { country: '!US' }
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Could anyone provide a solution?

Comment: If you want this feature with the Google Maps API, you can file a feature request for this through this link: https://developers.google.com/maps/support#issue_tracker

Comment: Yes I did request this feature. Here's the link to it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/280659994 

Need some more votes to grab some attention.

Answer (score 1):

There is no exclusion filter. You can only filter by inclusion with `componentRestrictions`, and you can only include up to 5 countries to include.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-multiple-countries

Comment: Yes that's what I found out from this documentation. Looks like there is no solution to my specific use case.